# C macros work different for gcc and MS Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, gcc, visual-studio-2017, c-preprocessor

pure C, part of code from [here](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin/blob/1.1.x/Marlin/macros.h)

```
#define _CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_0     0
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_1     1
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_      1
#define ENABLED(b) _CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, b)

// problem in this string if SOMETHING is not defined    
#if ENABLED(SOMETHING) 
int tmp;
#endif
```

This code is work for gcc, but in MS Visual Studio 2010 it give "error C2059: syntax error : 'bad suffix on number'" and "fatal error C1017 - invalid integer constant expression" for VS 2017.

How it is possible to modify code so that it can work for gcc and VS?

If it is not possible, what if analog code for VS? Something like

```
 #define ENABLED(X) #if defined(X) && #if X
```

Comment: You should specify the line number corresponding to the error

Comment: error in line #if ENABLED(SOMETHING) // problem

Comment: Do you need the suffixless `SWITCH_ENABLED_` macro?

Comment: Variadic macros were introduced with C99, and AFAIK VS 2010 does not support most C99 features.

Comment: What is the visual-studio-2017 tag for?

Comment: visual-studio-2017 tag I tested is pure win32 command string

Comment: `##__VA_ARGS__` is a non-standard extension

Comment: "Support for variadic macros was introduced in Visual C++ 2005."  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro

Comment: A macro cannot expand into a conditional.

Comment: It's unclear what you want.  Could you define the cases you want this to work for in your question?  (Simply showing code you want to "work" doesn't define what "work" means, and this belongs in your question). E.g., "should enter the `#if` when `SOMETHING` is defined with no body, defined as 1; should not enter if defined as 0 or undefined; should support other identifiers" etc, if this is what you're asking.

Comment: I want macro that work in MS VC in the same manner as it do in gcc/C99

Comment: That's not clarifying anything.  You're just saying that whatever "work" means to you, it should apply to MS as well as gnu.  What's unclear is what "work" means to you in the first place.  (FYI, it will be quite a while before I can personally revisit this question.)

Comment: I give a link to Marlin firmware at github. I want to port part of this code to Visual Studio, so "work" for me is compile code "as is" with minimum changes. And I rested against this macro

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
#define _CAT(a, ...) a ## __VA_ARGS__
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_false 0
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_true  1
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_0     0
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_1     1
#define SWITCH_ENABLED_      1
#define ENABLED(b) _CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, b)
#define DISABLED(b) (!_CAT(SWITCH_ENABLED_, b))
```

The minimal change you need is to replace `_CAT` with a non-variadic:

```
#define CAT(a,b) a##b
```

...in order to map the following to `0`:

- `SOMETHING` being undefined
- `SOMETHING` defined as `0`
- `SOMETHING` defined as `false`

...and the following to `1`:

- `SOMETHING` defined with no replacement list
- `SOMETHING` defined as `1`
- `SOMETHING` defined as `true`

...and will work with MSVS 2010 and most versions of gnu.